# Angular 2 app routing issue on aws cloud front

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We are migrating our existing website on angular 5 app. I have created static website on s3 and added error document url /new/index.html.

As idea is to serve everything on the same domain, angular app base-href is new. So it's served through /new and existing website will served as is.

To achieve this,in cloudfront i have added two origin one is old application served through load balancer and second new one served through s3 website. In behaviour path pattern new/* is served through s3 website and rest all (default *) should be through ec2 loadbalancer.

It works fine except one thing. Routing is not working correctly. Whenever I try to access specific url eg. mywebsite.com/new/auth/login it throws me back on mywebsite.com/new.

On s3 website same behaviour works fine. If i change default behaviour on cloudfront to s3 website. It works fine for angular app. But then I can't serve my existing app.

What i need to change in cloudfront to serve my angular routing correctly?

Comment: There could be some error, please add the error details.

Comment: there is no error. It shows me angular home page I set. Whereas same behaviour works fine on s3-website

Comment: you need both --deploy-url and --base-href set, optional --output-path if you want to deploy it somewhere

Comment: as I mentioned, if i set default behaviour in cloudfront as s3 website. Then it works. And if I check on s3 website it is working. Still let me check if --deploy-url set works or not

Answer (score 0):

There was session redirection written in angular by my developer by mistake. I had commented code and it's working as desired. Thanks.